# Static class stored as a property

Tags: c#, static-class

I have a static abstract class called **State**, it defines the abstract methods *start()* and *update()*, and then I have multiple classes which implement **State**.

Now I want to create a class, let's call it **StateMachine**, that has a property called *currentState*. I want to be able to set this property pointing to a static class implementing state so I can run things like *currentState.update()*.

Now comes my question:

What should be the type of the property? I'd say State but I feel like there's something more to it. Also, how would I go into setting the property? is

```
currentState = ClassThatImplementsState;
```

a valid thing to do?

**EDIT:** Ok, so I just learned that you cannot inherit from a static class in C#. I'd like to know a way of doing something similar to this that would allow me both the polymorfism and not having to instantiate the state objects. Is there such a thing?

Comment: You can't have a *static abstract class* in c#

Comment: property should be type `State`

Comment: you are trying to implement a state-machine? Fine you can do this with mutual-recursive functions (one for each state) - but typically all in the same static class ....

Comment: Yeah. I just realised static classes cannot be inherited in C#. Any more options to implement what I'm doing? I could go with non-static classes having only static methods?

Comment: nope - if you need only the functions you can get yourself some delegates or use Action<>/Func<>

Comment: you might want to get a bit background in what static/abstract/inheritance/OOP really is all about - sorry but I don't think that this is the format for a basic tutorial like this

Comment: Why does `State` and/or its methods need to be `static`?

Comment: @Setzer22 Why are you against creating instances? What's wrong with them? Static members doesn't participate in inheritance. Makes no sense also. This seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @D Stanley There's not really a need for it to be static, I just don't want to keep track of a bunch of State instances if I'm only going to use them  as as singleton and like a purely "functional" object, so given the same input, the output is guaranteed.

Comment: Don't use static classes, and don't create singletones. They are stupid and annoying. At least until you understand that a static class is just like a namespace to hold **functions** and not maintain **state**, and that a singletone is a good idea only if having multiple instances of something would **break** it.

Comment: @AK_: Agreed - But to make matters worse, static classes CAN maintain state ... but to use them that way means _abusing_ them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **State** is a *static* class, you can't have multiple classes that "implement", i.e. derive from it. When, on the other hand, it is an *abstract* class, you can derive from it. But it can't be both.

EDIT: I think what you actually want is a *Singleton* rather than an abstract or static class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx for hints how to implenent the Singleton pattern in C#.

EDIT 2: If your application is multithreaded, be sure to use a thread safe variant of the Singleton pattern.

Comment: Also, This should be a comment!

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a singleton. As static classes are a possible implementation for singletons but they don't really allow me to do what I want, I guess I'll try another implementation instead. Sorry for all the confusion.